# powershell script fails: This command cannot be run due to the error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: powershell

Trying to write my first powershell script to trigger an MSI.
The msi file is located in the same folder as the ps file.

**Problem**

I'm getting the error message in the title when i try to run.

```
PS C:\Users\jj\source\github\electron\j> .\test.ps1
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
At C:\Users\jj\source\github\electron\j\test.ps1:12 char:1
+ Start-Process .\node-v12.18.4-x64.msi -Wait -NoNewWindow
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

Yay.  Install script executed successfully
```

**Code**

This is what the code looks like:

```
$DataStamp = get-date -Format yyyyMMddTHHmmss
$logFile = '{0}-{1}.log' -f $file.fullname,$DataStamp
$MSIArguments = @(
    "/i"
    ('"{0}"' -f $file.fullname)
    "/qn"
    "/norestart"
    "/L*v"
    $logFile
)

Start-Process .\node-v12.18.4-x64.msi -ArgumentList $MSIArguments -Wait -NoNewWindow 
Write-Host "Yay.  Install script executed successfully"
```

**What I've tried**

I've tried triggering the msi directly from the powershell command line and it works fine.
Also removed all the commandline options in the ps file... but it still fails.

Lastly tried this for the start process command:

Start-Process -FilePath "$.\node-v12.18.4-x64.msi" -ArgumentList $MSIArguments -Wait -NoNewWindow

Any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your `$file` variable? That's not in your code you posted but it's referenced a few times.

Comment: I think you need to start `msiexec.exe` with the correct parameters (`/i` _filename_ ...).

Comment: I met with the same issue. Start-Process and msiexec.exe cannot work with the package, but direct trigger msi installation using ./<msi file> can complete successfully. Any ideas?